# Posts not showing in archive view

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a CPT called 'journal' and I have an archive-journal.php theme file to display the posts.  The posts are split into 4 categories. I have 4 if statements on the page to filter each category into a bootstrap tab using

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
    <?php if (in_category('cambridge-winter-college')) : ?>
```

The strange thing is that it is mostly working fine except some of the posts I have created are not showing up.  They are assigned to the correct categories but about 6 posts just refuse to show on the page.  Is there a default limit to the number of posts called by wordpress? pagination limit or something? My code is correct because they were showing earlier before I added more posts.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using single while loop and 4 if statement inside ?  Yes there is a default number of posts wordpress get in each loop, which is set to 10. The setting can be changed Setting -> Reading -> Blog pages show at most

Comment: Thats it, just needed to show more blog posts through that setting.  Is there a way to change the number of posts shown for a specific cpt?  The site will have a blog that is paginated.

Comment: And Yes, 4 if statements and 4 while loops.